# Python: Split String and convert to other type

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a function which could get a String formatted like this:

```
"true"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean>
"100"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>
```

Now i want to split the String on the `^^` Characters and convert the first part of the string based on the second part. I also want to remove the `"` first before converting.

This is my code which i use for this:

```py
def getValue(tObject):
    toReturn = tObject.split("^^")
    if len(toReturn) == 2:
        if toReturn[1] == "<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean>":
            return bool(toReturn[0].replace('"', ""))
        elif toReturn[1] == "<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>":
            return int(toReturn[0].replace('"', ""))
    return None
```

But i'm not so happy with it. Is there maybe a more elegant (pythonic) way to archive this?

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex, to

- check if the given value is valid
- retrieve the value to cast, and the way to cast

```
PATTERN = re.compile(r'"(.*)"\^\^<http:.*#(\w+)>')
types = {"boolean": bool, "int": int}

def getValue(value):
    m = PATTERN.fullmatch(value)
    return types[m.group(2)](m.group(1)) if m else None
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if len(...)` you could just try to unpack the result and except a `ValueError`. Then you can use a dict for the types and `str.strip` instead of `str.replace`:

```
types = {'boolean': bool, 'int': int}
try:
    value, type_hint = tObject.split('^^')
except ValueError:
    return None
else:
    return types[type_hint.rstrip('>').rsplit('#', 1)[1]](value.strip('"'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you could remove `return None`, since the function returns `None` by default.

Secondly, you could use `toReturn[1].endswith("boolean>")` to match the end of the string, instead of matching the whole string with `toReturn[1] == "<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean>"`. Same with the `int` string as well.

Thirdly, you could store the return value in one variable before the `if..elif`, then you don't have to calculate it twice for each condition.

**Code:**

```
def getValue(tObject):
    toReturn = tObject.split("^^")

    if len(toReturn) == 2:
        return_value = toReturn[0].replace('"', "")

        if toReturn[1].endswith("boolean>"):
            return bool(return_value)
        elif toReturn[1].endswith("int>"):
            return int(return_value)
```

This might not be much of a logic improvement, but the code does look less cluttered now. If you wan't more terse, "pythonic" ways of doing this problem, the other answers might be more suitable.